# React custom checkbox input component not rerendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

I'm extracting my checkbox input to separate custom component so I can easily reuse it later. But whenever the state on the parent changes, the checked value inside this custom component is not changing. It's actually changing when I move page first and open it later but not in real-time. But when I use default input component it works in real-time. Any idea how's this possible?

```
import React from 'react';

const Checkbox = ({ name, id, className, onValueChange, defaultChecked = false }) => {
  let classes = 'checkbox';

  if (className) {
    classes += ` ${className}`;
  }

  const valueChangeHandler = (event) => {
    if (onValueChange) {
      onValueChange(event.target.checked);
    }
  };

  return (
    <input 
      type="checkbox"
      name={ name }
      id={ id }
      className={ classes }
      defaultChecked={ defaultChecked }
      onChange={ valueChangeHandler }
    />
  );
};

export default Checkbox;
```

Comment: Can you try using `checked` instead of `defaultChecked` on input?

Comment: I've tried it. When I use checked, I can't change the input and it won't trigger onChange event.

Comment: Did you check if `defaultChecked` prop is being updated when `onValueChange` of parent is being called?

Comment: I'm using redux for the state. I've inspected the state many times with console.log and it's changing but the checkbox custom component is not changing in realtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest reading React's documentation around [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) and, more applicable to  your code, [uncontrolled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html).

Ideally, you want to use a controlled component, which usually consists of a `value` and `onValueChanged` prop or similar:

```
const Checkbox = ({ name, id, className, value, onValueChange }) => {
  const valueChangeHandler = (event) => {
    if (onValueChange) onValueChange(event.target.checked);
  };

  return (
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      name={name}
      id={id}
      checked={!!value}
      className={className ? `checkbox ${className}` : 'checkbox'}
      onChange={valueChangeHandler}
    />
  );
};
```

Which you'd then use like this:

```
function SomeComponent() {
    const defaultValue = true;
    const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(defaultValue);

    return <div>
        <Checkbox
            value={checked}
            onValueChange={setChecked}
            ...
        />
    </div>;
}
```

Basically, if you expect to change the checkbox's value from the parent, you require a controlled component where you tell your checkbox what value it should be. Here we simply keep track of the value with `React.useState`, which conveniently accepts a default value. You could replace `useState` with e.g. a redux-based getter/setter instead.

Comment: Hey. thanks for the answer. This approach works for me :D. It looks like I still can't differentiate the behavior of checked and defaultChecked.

Comment: `defaultChecked` basically says "when this `<input>` elements gets first created, have it be (un)checked" but your problem is that you change the value, which I assume you pass through `defaultChecked`, but the `<input>` has already rendered. Now if you make use of controlled components, e.g. `value`, then the checkbox value will be what **you** say it is, at all times. React recommends controlled components for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

The input 'defaultChecked' is setted only for the first time  (when it is loaded), so it doesn't change when the value change.
You should pass the new value to the 'checked' attribute,
so try this :

```js
import React from 'react';

const Checkbox = ({ name, id, className, onValueChange, defaultChecked = false }) => {
  let classes = 'checkbox';

  if (className) {
    classes += ` ${className}`;
  }

  const valueChangeHandler = (event) => {
    if (onValueChange) {
      onValueChange(event.target.checked);
    }
  };

  return (
    <input 
      type="checkbox"
      name={ name }
      id={ id }
      className={ classes }
      defaultChecked={ defaultChecked }
      checked={defaultChecked}
      onChange={ valueChangeHandler }
    />
  );
};

export default Checkbox;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yeah my problem is using defaultChecked insted of checked. I still can't differentiate defaultChecked and checked. Really appreciate it :D